# How to use sed to replace text with a file path?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I'm writing a bash script where I need to replace text in a file with a specific file path, but my understanding is that `sed` does not work with specific characters such as `/`. I'm wondering if there is some way around this?

Here is my script currently:

```
currentdir="$PWD"
filepathvar="${currentdir}/settings.ini"

sed -i -e "s/filepath/$filepathvar/g" aimparmstest
```

When I print out `filepathvar` everything is as I expect it to be, but it seems the fact that `filepathvar` contains special characters, it gives me the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'
```

Is there any way around this? Or perhaps another command I can use? I haven't had any success with changing around the parameters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any character as the separator (the first character). For example:

```
echo "a/b/c" | sed -e 's|/|_|g'
```

In your case:

```
sed -i -e "s|filepath|$filepathvar|g" aimparmstest
```

Comment: Thank you! All the examples I read up on using sed had forward slash as the separator so I had no idea this was flexible.